# What prevents the callee from cleaning up the stack?

Tags: assembly, theory, calling-convention

As part of extending my curriculum, I'm slowly descending down the ladder of programming abstraction. Right now I have good command of C, and I'm making preparations for writing some assembly (ARM assembly, specifically).

I've encountered the topic of calling conventions, and while I generally understand their sense, the question that never seems to be asked or answered is:

*Why can't the callee handle variable arguments on the stack?*

Everywhere it says that the called function doesn't know how many parameters have been passed, but in that case why isn't it possible to simply put that data into a register or push it onto the top of the stack for the called function to use?

I'm asking this question with respect to any architecture that utilises stacks for subroutine communication, not just ARM or x86.

Comment: well i thought in some conventions callee cleans up the stack, such as pascal convention http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#pascal

Comment: I'm curious where your "everywhere" is; you seem to have made a very poor or unlucky choice of sources to include in "everywhere". :)

Comment: By the way I put this link in my answer but it's useful enough to put here too: http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf has more than you'd ever want to know. While they discuss x86 and amd64, the concepts are precisely the same for any stack-based architecture (I also work frequently with OMAP and straight ARM devices, it's all the same).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no fundamental reason why the callee couldn't clean up space for variables. In most architectures, the standard calling convention doesn't handle variables this way, but that doesn't mean it's not possible to do so. For variable-length argument lists, you could either pass data about the number of arguments as a hidden parameter (like how `this` is handled in many object-oriented languages), or put a pointer on the stack that shows where the arguments end, etc.

The fact that it currently *isn't* done this way doesn't mean that it *must* be done this way. It's good to question why things are the way they are, and in this case I think the reason is "it's slightly easier to implement varargs this way, and since all the other cool kids were doing it, we should do it too." After all, if all compiled C binaries handle parameters this way, it would be really rough to try to interoperate with those binaries if you had a different calling convention. (As an example of this, look at the Windows API, where certain functions have to be annotated to use a nonstandard calling convention in order to operate with the OS.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's worth noting that nearly every function in the Windows API uses `__stdcall` (callee clean up).

Answer (score 5):

The callee can clean variable arguments from the stack. I made it once, actually. But the code is pretty big.

Anyway, the main reason why in **cdecl** convention, the caller cleans the stack is other. (The variable arguments procedures are very few, after all)

On some architectures (usually very small, as the old 8080 or 6800), there is no `ret n` instruction that to automate the stack cleaning and as a rule they can't make arithmetics with the stack pointer as well.

So, the callee have to first pop the return address from the stack in order to reach the arguments, then to pop all arguments and then push back the return address. For 3 arguments it will look this way with **stdcall** convention:

```
    push arg1
    push arg2
    push arg3
    call proc

proc:
    pop  r1   ; the return address
    pop  r2
    pop  r2
    pop  r2
    push r1
    ret
```

When **cdecl** convention is used 2 instructions and one register use are spared:

```
    push arg1
    push arg2
    push arg3
    call proc
    pop  r2
    pop  r2
    pop  r2

proc:
    ret
```

And because for single language it is better to use single calling convention on all platforms, the CCALL as more simple and universal looks better. (C language is created in times when 6800 was a high tech).

But notice, that on these platforms, the assembly programs and the native languages (for example different kind of BASICs) usually use register argument passing which is of course much more faster on such small systems.

Anyway, it is just a tradition. You can set the compiler to use whatever convention you want. For example, WinAPI is written in C++ but still uses **stdcall** convention, because it is better on x86 platform.

Comment: What calling convention do you mean by "CCALL"? cdecl or something else I don't know about?

Answer (score 2):

The callee can most certainly clean up the stack. There is absolutely no fundamental reason why this can't be the case, and in fact many compilers support code that explicitly declares a calling convention.

It is worth noting that nearly every single function in the entire Windows API uses a calling convention where the callee cleans the stack.

For an overview of common calling conventions on x86, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions.

For a detailed look at general calling conventions on many compilers (concepts are identical for any functional stack-based architecture, be it x86, powerpc, arm, avr, etc.), see http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf.

For the common "stdcall" calling convention, where the callee cleans the stack, here is a Microsoft-specific document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx But that calling convention is supported by many compilers. Note that the MS compiler makes functions with variable arguments cdecl instead.

There are a few widely used calling conventions (e.g. "cdecl", "stdcall", "fastcall") that are typically supported by many compilers, but if you are coding in assembler or you feel like writing compiler patches, you are free to come up with any weird and wacky convention you can imagine (well, within reason).

I'm not sure where the "everywhere" in your statement "Everywhere it says that the called function ..." is, but you're either misunderstanding or you have a very poor/unlucky choice of "everywhere".

By the way: It is good that you are asking this question; if you are writing assembler, and especially if you are integrating it with code generated from another language, it is important to be aware of and honor the calling convention used by that other code, whatever it may be.

Comment: "Everywhere" means exactly the type of documents like the one from Microsoft, along with learning materials that teach x86.

Comment: @ThomasK. Just out of curiosity, can you post a reference to one of those Microsoft documents? This is not a criticism, just an observation, but I believe you may have misinterpreted what they were saying. Vararg functions aside, a function implicitly knows exactly what parameters are passed to it by its definition. Consider a C function `void __stdcall something (int x)`. By calling convention, the compiler's generated code for that function includes popping a 4 byte (e.g.) integer off of the stack. Function calls are generated to push a 4 byte value, call it, and presume correct handling.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall, for example, for the "contract" specified by stdcall functions (BTW, for your reference, the containing section in that wiki article pertains specifically to callee-cleanup conventions). Bear in mind that a calling convention *is* a "contract". There is a set of them that is commonly used, and those are the ones you find described (e.g. cdecl, stdcall, fastcall). In reality you can come up with anything you want, but you run a risk of compatibility issues with existing tools made to work only with common conventions.

Comment: It is also worth noting that when interfacing with other binary objects, you *must* honor the calling convention they expect. For example, if calling a Windows API function from assembler, you are responsible for pushing arguments onto the stack in right-to-left order, and you are reasonable in making assumptions about the state of the stack when that function returns. For cdecl functions (the usual default for C compilers), you are likewise responsible for adhering to those rules when calling those functions, and making associated assumptions about the state of the stack on return.

Answer (score 0):

The called function absolutely knows how many parameters are defined at least, if the caller and callee dont agree on the number of parameters you are eventually going to get into trouble.  But if the caller and callee agree then certainly the callee knows the number of parameters that have been sent.

it is simply a convention.  It is a nice convention because the creator of the thing cleans it up.  it is self contained.  The user of the thing (stack frame/parameters) just uses them.  If it becomes a caller then it manages that aspect of the stack...

At the end of the day though it is simply a convention.  You are welcome to create or modify a compiler which uses a different standard.

if the language and calling convention allow then there is no reason why the callee wouldnt be able to handle an arbitrary number of parameters.  it is quite easy to implement this actually.  It is just not a common use case so not normally an interesting topic.  it is also not that efficient, if you have a lot of things you want to send do it by reference not by value.  So again not an interesting topic, when the overall functionality is already supported.

Comment: `The called function absolutely knows how many parameters are defined at least, if the caller and callee dont agree on the number of parameters you are eventually going to get into trouble.` For languages that use late parameter evaluation (e.g., checking to see whether the parameter actually holds a value, has been initialized, etc.), isn't this *not* the case? Languages that support variable-length argument lists that are determined at run-time - are these counter-examples? Maybe I'm just guessing...

Comment: the code generation for both caller and callee know the rules, if it is declared as dynamic they both know, have to for the code to work.  If they dont both know (compile time or runtime) then that is a compiler bug or a programmers bug by not matching the declaration for caller and callee.

Comment: Good point! I just wanted to be sure - I'm learning about parameter evaluation and data control at my university; it just seemed to be that your statement didn't really add up. Makes sense though when I think about it more :)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few reasons:

1. Cleaning the arguments involves changing the stack address pointer(`esp`). When the caller is responsible for it, all the callee have to do with `esp` is return it to how it found it, and when the caller regains control `esp` is just the same as it left it. If the callee was the one to clean the arguments, it would have to calculate the new value for `esp`(rather than just pop the old value from the stack), and the caller would have to take into account how the callee changed it. This would make things more complex for both caller and callee.
2. In C++, cleaning arguments also means calling the destructors for temporary objects. The callee can't call the destructor for objects passed as arguments - since it doesn't if they are temporary objects or not. Only the caller knows which arguments are temporary objects and which are not.
3. The callee doesn't know what happens *after* it's execution is finished and the control is returned to the caller. Therefore, cleaning the arguments in the caller leaves more options for optimization. For example, using the same arguments(possibly with a few changes) to make another call to another function, or returning from the caller right away without cleaning the arguments at all(they will simply be tossed off with the rest of the stack frame).